# How to add a multipoint layer in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I try to add a multipoint layer to a leaflet map. code:
L.marker([[3.9, 43.9],[4.2, 44.1]]).addTo(myMap);
gives the following error: "leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'lat')".

leaflet doc doesnt mention multipoint layers. How to add/display a multipoint layer in leaflet ?

Comment: Leaflet doesn't care about multipoint geometries (or the rest of the OGC Simple Features Specification, for that matter). Iterate through the points in your multipoint and spawn a marker per point.

Comment: Thanks. I could miss some features however. For example, how can I zoom on a group of markers (related by a theme) instead of individual markers doing this?

Comment: Use `L.LayerGroup`s.